# How to add rich text content programmatically using Managed Client Object Model?

Tags: client-object-model, rich-text

I am building a Silverlight application that interacts with SharePoint through Managed Client Object Model. One of the functionalities of the app is to update a list item field with rich text content.

I don't know how to pass rich text content to SharePoint. HTML styling doesn't work because SharePoint adds the content literally.

For example, I want to write

> SharePoint **is** *awesome*.

but the following doesn't work:

> `SharePoint <b>is</b> <i>awesome</i>.`

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using the "Enhanced rich text"?

Comment: Actually no, I am using a Multi line text box with the type of text set to "Rich text"

Comment: Can you set the multi line textbox to "Enhanced rich text"-type?

Comment: @RubenHerman Sure, I can. I don't see that helping me much. I need to programmatically fill that field with formatted text, i.e. bold, italic, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`<a>`, `<div>` `<p>` and probably a couple of more tags are supported.

To apply styles use inline style approach; for example:
`<p style="background: blue; color: white;">A style is applied with inline CSS</p>`